# A valid Gruntfile could not be found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mean-stack

I have followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) to try to install a `mean.js` stack on an ubuntu server.

Regarding `grunt`, in `/opt/mean`, I have done

```
sudo npm install -g bower grunt-cli
sudo npm install grunt --save-dev
sudo npm install
```

However, `grunt` or `grunt jshint` inside the folder gives

> A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started
>   guide for more information on how to configure grunt:
>   http://gruntjs.com/getting-started 
>   Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.

Note that `npm start` works, and `http://server_domain_or_IP:3000` can display the sample application.

Does anyone know how to fix the grunt error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, you do not have a Gruntfile and https://gruntjs.com/getting-started shows you an example of one.

Simply installing Grunt is not enough. When you run `grunt` it needs a configuration file (your Gruntfile) to run any tasks. The Gruntfile itself contains the tasks to be run.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a Gruntfile.js in your project. you can create the same using the following grunt command.

```
grunt-init gruntfile
```

The above command will create the sample gruntfile.js file in your project.